# How to kill SQL Server process derived from determined ASP.MVC App

Tags: sql, sql-server, pool

I have 3 ASP.MVC App on one Server (hostname), hence, I have 3 different AppPool.
Also, I have one SQL Server DB and each of application using it.

**My question:** Is it possible kill only these processes derived from one ASP.MVC App?

Answer (score 1):

This *might* help you safely determine the SPIDs to kill:

```
 select spid, program_name
 from sys.sysprocesses
 order by program_name
```

Comment: Do you can show the user name from each spid in this query?

Comment: @EdgardLeal Yes, sys.sysprocesses has a Loginname column which can be used to determine the database user.

Comment: Good. I think this can answer the question.